# Overriding templates in Meteor AccountsEntry

Tags: authentication, meteor

I cannot figure out how to do it. But I see projects that have accountsEntry templates like "entrySignUp" and "entrySignIn" with integrated directly into their apps. I was able to attach a header by rejecting AccountEntry's package routes and overriding them. But that also override the Account templates functionality.

Please help!

Comment: Try to use alternative to `AccountsEntry`, which is http://atmospherejs.com/splendido/accounts-templates-core

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using accounts-templates-bootstrap for the time being. I was also hoping to use accountsEntry partially because I wanted to learn to extend a meteor package in my project. I haven't had much luck finding out a good way to do that.